# What does char* do or mean as a return type for a function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, return-type

I have a program that was set up for me and I just had to fill in the blanks.  There was one function at the bottom that I didn't have to touch but don't understand why the return type of the function was `char*` and not just `char`.

```
/*Main Function from where it is called */

char * check(char * name, double sx[], double t[], int n);

/*Function*/

char * check(char * name, double sx[], double t[], int n)
{

int i;
for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {    
        if(fabs(sx[i] - t[i]) > EPSILON)
            return (strcat(name, " check fails"));
        else
            return (strcat(name, " check is OK"));
    }
}
```

I don't understand why that is.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the function does not return a single character. Instead it returns an address which POINTS to a character (hence the name *pointer*), and it is denoted by a `*`. This is necessary because you do not use a single character, but rather a list of characters, to form a sentence (or string).

As a string ends with a '\0' character, other functions can iterate through the memory until they reach this character. Please read this part on pointers: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c20.htm

Or better: read the entire C tutorial. It is well written and should clarify a lot.

Answer (score 0):

char* means a pointer to a character. In C strings are an array of characters terminated by the null character.

Answer (score 0):

char* is a pointer to the first char in the return "string" (char array).
although the size of the array isn't given, in C "string"s are null terminated. meaning you can start reading the chars of the position the pointer is set to until you encounter a null char ('\0').